# how to display Hindi content in windows phone7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

how to display Hindi content in windows phone7 ?

i have Hindi content(language ) how to display this local language in Browser control .

or any textbox or rich text box?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Have you gone through http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/brijrajsingh/glbal_102132006022647AM/glbal_1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The only mention of Hindi support was back in January 2012 which stated that unfortunatley Windows Phone 7 does not support the Hindi font style and at the time of writing, cannot support installation of custom fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are looking for is to embed a font that does support Hindi glyps. You can follow the following tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robcamer/archive/2010/06/26/embed-a-font-in-a-windows-phone-7-application.aspx